# Android Studio's Terminal is garbled in Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, terminal

Android Studio 3.0

Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 21, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Mac OS X 10.12.4

[Chinese char garbled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8KOE.jpg)

Comment: Voting to close because this appears to just be a bug report. Bug reports should be sent to the developers directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`.